# What is the difference between "Updated" and "LastUpdated" in Request Tracker?

Tags: rt

In the [Request Tracker REST API](https://rt-wiki.bestpractical.com/wiki/REST), I have access to the `LastUpdated` field. However, if I use the Query Builder tool, I can use `Updated` or `LastUpdated`. What are the differences between these two fields?

Answer (score 1):

`LastUpdated` is the date of last transaction in the ticket. `Updated` means if the ticket was updated on the given date.

For example imagine a ticket `12345` created `1.1.2019` then not touched and closed `3.1.2019`. When you search for `(id = 12345 AND Updated = '2019-01-01')`, RT gives you the ticket `12345`. If you search for `(id = 12345 AND Updated = '2019-01-02')`, RT wouldn't find anything as well as if you search for `(id = 12345 AND LastUpdated = '2019-01-01')`. Because the `LastUpdated` date would be `2019-01-03`.

To use the `Updated` date through REST API you should use the query: `/REST/1.0/search/ticket?query=...`.

Comment: I've wondered about that for years. Makes perfect sense. Thank you. :)